# Não foi possível criar um valor constante de tipo 'System.Object'. Apenas tipos primitivos ou tipos de enumeração têm suporte nesse contexto

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta em LINQ, e está retornando a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Não foi possível criar um valor constante de tipo 'System.Object'. Apenas tipos primitivos ou tipos de enumeração têm suporte nesse contexto

Uma estrutura é recursiva, então uma estrutura pode ser filha de outra.

Quando eu recebo o `idPai`, eu quero que ele me traga somente os filhos daquela estrutura, e quando eu passar o `id`, eu quero aquela estrutura específica, daquele `idPai`.

A Action seria assim:

```
Estrutura/{idPai}/{id}
```

A query é a seguinte:

```
var list = (from e in ent.Estrutura
join t in ent.TipoEstrutura on e.idTipoEstrutura equals t.id

join ee in ent.Estrutura on e.idEstrutura equals ee.id into eleft
from ePai in eleft.DefaultIfEmpty()


where ((idPai.HasValue ? e.idEstrutura.Equals(id) : e.idEstrutura.Equals(null))
        && (id.HasValue ? e.id.Equals(id) : e.id != null))

select new SigProcessos.Entity.ViewModel.Estrutura
{
    Id = e.id,
    IdEstrutura = e.idEstrutura,
    IdTipoEstrutura = t.id,
    DescricaoEstrutura = e.descricao,
    DescricaoEstruturaPai = (null != ePai ? ePai.descricao : default(string))
}).ToList();

return list;
```

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Seu default(string) é o que?

Comment: É Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Experimente trocar seus `.Equals()` por "==".

Como você possui variáveis que provavelmente são do tipo `int?`, pode estar dando problema porque o programa pode estar tentando fazer `.Equals()` com tipos incorretos ( exemplo: `int?.Equals(int)` ).